# How to update session token when using Amplify Signer.signUrl() for transformWsUrl() in mqtt connect client options in React?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-iot, mqtt.js

I have an IoT React application that uses Cognito for federated authentication, and AWS IoT Core as the IoT broker. I am using Amplify and mqtt libraries in the project.

I need to create a signed url to connect to the broker.

I am doing this like so:

```
import { MqttClient, connect } from 'mqtt'
import { API, Auth, Signer } from 'aws-amplify'
...
const {accessKeyId, secretAccessKey,sessionToken} = await Auth.currentCredentials()
const signedUrl = generateSignedUrl({accessKeyId, secretAccessKey, sessionToken})

connect(signedUrl , {
...
transformWsUrl: () => generateSignedUrl({accessKeyId, secretAccessKey, sessionToken})
})
...

function generateSignedUrl({accessKeyId, secretAccessKey, sessionToken}) {
...
return Signer.signUrl(
    endpoint,
    {
      access_key: accessKeyId,
      secret_key: secretAccessKey,
      session_token: sessionToken
    },
    serviceInfo
  )
}
```

This works initially. But eventually (especially on mobile if the tab is inactive for 1+ hours), I get a 403 error when I try to reconnect to my mqtt broker. I am guessing this is because I now have a new session token, but am still passing the old one to `generateSignedUrl()`. However, since `transformWsUrl()` does not accept Promises, I don't know where to retrieve the new tokens to pass to `generateSignedUrl()`.

How can I pass updated tokens to `transformWsUrl()` once they have been renewed in this case?

Thanks.